# Arduino lambdas 'no suitable conversion function from' error

Tags: c++, lambda, arduino

I have small Arduino project that using lambas:

```
typedef void(*keyboardKeyDelegate)(int);

void KeyboardKeyChange(int button, keyboardKeyDelegate onKeyChange);
void KeyboardKeyChange(int button, keyboardKeyDelegate onKeyChange)
{
    // code...
}

void KeyboardKeyClick(int button, keyboardKeyDelegate onClick);
void KeyboardKeyClick(int button, keyboardKeyDelegate onClick)
{
    // code...
}
```

.. next

```
bool r = true;
KeyboardKeyClick(KB_TOP, [&r](int state)
{
    r = !r;
    Serial.println("> KB_TOP CLICKED");
});
```

I have an error while compiling source:

```
no suitable conversion function from "lambda []void (int state)->void" to "keyboardKeyDelegate" exists
```

Maybe someone knows more about this error and help me to figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda has state and is thus not convertible to a functionpointer like the function argument.

You need to either remove the state from your lambda and recover it someway, or change the function to accept any callable by turning it into a template.